# Pass data from django middleware.process_view to the template context

Tags: python, django

I have a custom middleware and during its process_view I get some token. And I need to pass this token to the rendered result html.

I thought that context_processor is a good place to modify context, but looks like it's hard to pass some data from middleware into processor.

But it seems that the only way to communicate for process_view and context processor is request object. And if set any field to the request I get 'WSGIRequest' object does not support item assignment' error. Here is a pieces of code:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
   ...
   with log(request, view_func.__name__, info) as id:

      request['TOKEN_ID'] = logger.get().get_id() #here is an error
      response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

So, looks like I'm doing something wrong. Is there a way to communicate middleware.process_view and context_processor? Or I should change another way to pass data into html from middleware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is raised when you try and use dictionary item assignment:

```
request['my_key'] = 'my_value'
```

But the request is not a dictionary, it is an object. As with all objects - like the Django models which you must be familiar with - you need to set attributes, not items.

```
request.my_attribute = 'my_value'
```

(Next time, please show the code you used and the full traceback you got.)

Comment: Yep, I thought about to add the code but actually it looked so simple and 'default' that I believed that it is not needed. Anyway I added it since it was my code issue. Thanks!

Comment: @daniel-roseman: If we need to pass a variable to any template(using middleware). Which is better approach setting attributes to request object in middleware of it is better to use context processor and pass to middleware?